# Cohomologies of anticanonical sheaf of blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in 9 points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

Let $\pi:X\to\mathbb{P}^2$ be a blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in 9 points (in general position for example, but it doesn't matter). Then the canonical divisor of $X$ is equal $K_X=-3\pi^*H+\sum\limits_{k=1}^9E_k$, where $E_k$, $k=1,...,9$ are exceptional divisors. It is known and not hard to compute that $-K_X\sim C$, where $C$ is a proper transform cubic curve on $\mathbb{P}^2$, which passes through that 9 points. I want to compute $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X(-K_X))$. By Riemann-Roch, $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X(-K_X))=1$. From the identification of $-K_X$ we need to compute $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X(C))$.

Let us write the exact sequence

$$0\to\mathcal{O}_{X}\to\mathcal{O}_{X}(C)\to\mathcal{O}_{C}(C)\to0.$$

But $C\cdot C=K_X\cdot K_X=0$, so the third term is actually $\mathcal{O}_{C}$.

Taking the long exact sequence of cohomologies we obtain

$$0\to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})\to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(C))\to H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_{C})\to0.$$
Thus $\text{dim}\,H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(-K_X))=2$. But this result doesn't coincide with the result from Sándor Kovács's answer for the following question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107345/blowing-up-general-k-points-on-the-plane

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you rightly say, $O_C(C)$ is a line bundle of degree zero on $C$, but that **doesn't** mean it's the trivial bundle. (Remember $C$ is an elliptic curve, so it has lots of non-trivial degree zero line bundles.)

In fact $O_C(C) \simeq O_C$ if and only if the 9 blowup points are the intersection of two cubic curves in the plance, in which case the result $h^0(-K_X)=2$ is completely correct. Otherwise, $O_C(C)$ is a non-trivial degree zero bundle on $C$, in which case $h^0(O_C(C))=0$ and hence $h^0(-K_X)=1$, as you expect.

Comment: Could you explain please why then $h^0(O_C(C))=0$?

Comment: If a nontrivial line bundle (on any variety) has a nonzero section, then that section vanishes on a nonempty proper closed subset. On curves, that means that a nontrivial line bundle with a nonzero section has strictly positive degree.